# Untrackable Error: Unrecognized field "notBefore" (class org.keycloak.representations.idm.UserRepresentation)

Tags: scala, jackson, keycloak

I hope you can help me out here. I need to relaunch a project again after the development got stopped about half a year ago. It consists out of different microservices. Mainly a Scala Swagger API based on the Play framework. But for securing their application and the users they are using keycloak.
While fetching the user profile the following internal server error occurs:

```
 "javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException:  
  Unrecognized field "notBefore" (class org.keycloak.representations.idm.UserRepresentation), not marked as ignorable  
 (24 known properties: "disableableCredentialTypes", "enabled", "emailVerified", "origin", "self", "applicationRoles", "createdTimestamp", "clientRoles", "groups", "username", "totp", "id", "email", "federationLink", "serviceAccountClientId", "lastName", "clientConsents", "socialLinks", "realmRoles", "attributes", "firstName", "credentials", "requiredActions", "federatedIdentities"])
 at [Source: org.apache.http.conn.EofSensorInputStream@3101000d; line: 1, column: 369] (through reference chain: org.keycloak.representations.idm.UserRepresentation["notBefore"])"
```

At other endpoints I get a similiar error as this one, except there is another field missing in the definition.
The Keycloak server runs on version 3.4.0.Final and the dependecies are all to version 3.4.0.Final upgraded.

```
keycloak-services  
keycloak-admin-client
keycloak-adapter-core
keycloak-authz-client
```

Can anyone help me out?
Thanks in advance

**Solution**
My docker-images did not pull the current version. So the dependencies stayed as the were in my running environment.

Comment: Make sure that you use the same version of the keycloak on all nodes particularly the client (caller) node and the server node.

Comment: First of all thank you very much for your comment. I looked into the server version and my pom before recompiling and packing ist again. I still get the same error. My client is on version 4.3.0.Final as is my server.

Comment: Well, as `notBefore` was only added by a [commit](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/commit/fe5891fbdb195f7a18601c6b530a647e80dba8be) just a few month ago it really looks like serialization and deserialization of different versions of the same class. Might there be involved some long-term caching of JSON?